# How do I bind a List<CustomObject> to a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm new to WPF and want to do some basic databinding.
I have a List of a CustomObject and want to bind it to a DataGrid.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace WpfApplication1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                List<ArticleItem> list = new List<ArticleItem>() 
                {
                new ArticleItem(){ ID=3, Title="test", ViewCount=5},
                new ArticleItem(){ ID=3, Title="test", ViewCount=5},
                new ArticleItem(){ ID=3, Title="test", ViewCount=5},
                new ArticleItem(){ ID=3, Title="test", ViewCount=5},
                };
            }
        }

        public class ArticleItem 
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int ViewCount { get; set; }
            public String Title { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

This is how my grid looks like:

```
<DataGrid Height="179" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,65,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="382">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewCount" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm used to the databinding from ASP.Net, where I can easily say:

```
this.dataGrid1.DataSource = list;
```

How must I proceed in WPF?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

if you do not expect that your `list` will be recreated then you can use the same approach as you've used for Asp.Net (instead of `DataSource` this property in WPF is usually named `ItemsSource`):

```
this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
```

But if you would like to replace your `list` with new collection instance then you should consider using `databinding`.

Comment: I have multiple rows in a DataGrid in which each of the datagrid row has a button which opens  a popup on its click and in the Popup i have another datagrid with button, Now Onclick of this button i want to take the respective row data from which the button is clicked and add this row data to the first dataGrid Row from which the pop-up is opened.

Answer (score 24):

You should do it in the xaml code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding list}" [...]>
  [...]
</DataGrid>
```

I would advise you to use an `ObservableCollection` as your backing collection, as that would propagate changes to the datagrid, as it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: I don't get it. I moved to list up to a instance variable und used this xaml attributes for the DataGrid: ItemsSource="{Binding list}" AutoGenerateColumns="true". Upon exception I see an empty DataGrid with no rows and no columns

Comment: it needs to be a property for data binding. Also, have a look into the output window, usually there is some information that will help you figure out the problem.

Comment: @citronas: Besides make the List a property, the `DataGrid` will also need to have a DataContext for the Binding to work. Set `this.DataContext = this;` in the constructor for `MainWindow` and it should work

Comment: @Meleak, do not ever set self DataContext in control constructor! You would better learn OP to use `RelativeSource` binding property.

Comment: This is a better answer, the accepted answer will functionality doesn't sync well with the datagrid. You need to manually call `dataGrid.Items.Refersh()` when there is a changed, and that call doesn't got off it filtered by clicking a column. Using a `ObservableCollection` fixes all of that.

Comment: @Femaref Thanks for the explanation on ObservableCollection! I was trying to just use a List<> to no avail, but the collection works perfectly.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, to properly support sorting, filtering, etc. a CollectionViewSource should be used as a link between the DataGrid and the list, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The DataGrid line looks like this:

```
<DataGrid
  DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

In the code behind, you link CollectionViewSource with your link.

```
CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource;
itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));
itemCollectionViewSource.Source = itemList;
```

For detailed example see my article on CoedProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings

Comment: Love this approach - have you enhanced this in a reusable way in the past couple years?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "a reusable way".By the way, Visual Studio is generating a similar code when you drop a table from the "Data Sources" Window onto the WPF Window.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to give column names manually in xaml. Just set AutoGenerateColumns property to true and your list will be automatically binded to DataGrid. refer code.
XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="447" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="799"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListTest, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  CanUserAddRows="False"> </Grid>
```

C#

```
Public Class Test 
{
    public string m_field1_Test{get;set;}
    public string m_field2_Test { get; set; }
    public Test()
    {
        m_field1_Test = "field1";
        m_field2_Test = "field2";
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {

        listTest = new List<Test>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            obj = new Test();
            listTest.Add(obj);

        }

        this.MyDatagrid.ItemsSource = ListTest;

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Originally I didn't have the `get` and `set`, which meant nothing was being generated and I was confused.

Comment: `this.MyDatagrid.XXX` will nullref exception before `InitalizeComponent()`