# editing DataGrid cells and binding some cells to each other in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

On a DataGrid i have the columns : Last counter,Current counter, Current kilos.What I want is to enter the data for columns : Last counter,Current counter and the Current kilos column will get its data by subtracting the current counter from the (last counter). I want to do that directly on the DataGrid.
Is there any way to bind columns to other columns to do what i asked for in Xaml?

This is the Xaml code of the DataGrid

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="1" Name="grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,163,0,10" 
        MinRowHeight="26" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" Background="LightBlue"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cfname}"  Header="First name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cmname}"  Header="Middle name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding clname}"  Header="Last name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding address}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Address"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding boxnumber}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="box number"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding discount}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Discount"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding typeofsub}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="subscription type"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ampere}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="subscription"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding required}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Fee"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding lastkilos}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Last counter"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn  ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="current counter"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="current kilos"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="price"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Total cost"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: XAML is for layout.  XAML does not do data logic/math.  Best you get is a trigger = logic.  It would be easy enough to do in the class.

Comment: Ok how can i do that in code behind then?. I am using C#

Comment: What is the DataSource?

Comment: I get the data from SQL Server to fill a Datatable using a Dataadapter then I bind the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to the Datatable

Comment: OH, well then I don't think you can do it with a Datatable.  You would need to use a class with public properties.  Read into the objects using a reader and put them in a List and bind to the list.

Comment: Ok, then you asked me to use a list box because i can't fill the DataGrid using a Datareader? because if i can do that then my problem will be solved

Comment: In WPF you should use an intermediary class (typically referred to as an Entity) to hold your data that you load from the database. Then you bind your UI to this class. You can add a property to this class that represents the formula and just raise this propertychanged event whenever the properties within the formula change.

Comment: I did not say list box I said List.  You can bind a DataGrid to a List .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983951/how-do-i-bind-a-listcustomobject-to-a-wpf-datagrid