# Bind customObject to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

The basics of binding a list of objects to a DataGrid are discussed here  [How do I bind a List<CustomObject> to a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983951/how-do-i-bind-a-listcustomobject-to-a-wpf-datagrid).

My setup is slightly more complex:
I have `RowModels` which contain metadata for the row as well as a list of `CellModels`. The `CellModels` again contain some metadata and a `Value` property which is shown in the dataGrid.

To fill my DataGrid I did set

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RowModelList, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged}"
```

and mapped the columns one-by-one via

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CellModelList[0].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CellModelList[1].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged}"/>
...
```

This way i could also specify a ColumnHeader for each column and modify the presentation of each column.

However i would like to also use a `DataTrigger` in my `DataGridCell`-Style to access the metadata of my CellModels.

**this works, but.. well**:

Of course I could create a Style for each column like

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyleColumnZero" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CellModelList[0].Enabled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Question:**

I need to set Properties of the `DataGridCell` depending on the metadata in my `CellModel`.

I am sure there is a more elegant solution (than the one shown above) which doesn't require customizing every single column. I still need to be able to manually change single columns (especially the `ColumnHeaders`) which is why i manually declared the DataGridTextColumns one-by-one in the first place.

Do you have any suggestions how to approach this properly?

Comment: Use C# Reflection for this elegant solution. It can list you the metadata of `CellModel`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. By metadata I meant the properties (like Enabled, Value, etc.) within `CellModel`. The issue is that in the current solution the `CellModel` is not bound to the DataGridCell (only the `Value` Property is). Thus I can not access the `CellModel` via databinding from within a `DataGridCell`-Style.

Comment: Why can't you just cast Value to CellModel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in a followup question.

The solution i used was creating an attached property for `DataGridCell` in which i store the CellModel and access the properties from there.

See the linked question for code:
[Structure of WPF DataGrid - change cells depending on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910396/structure-of-wpf-datagrid-change-cells-depending-on-value)