# Structure of WPF DataGrid - change cells depending on value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I did bind an Object to a `DataGridTextColumn` and would like to reference one of its properties from within the corresponding CellStyle. I assumed that each cell of this column would contain an instance of `MyObject`. However I can't find a reference to the Object from within the `DataGridCell` (I used a trivial converter to set a break point and searched the `DataGridCell`-object for quite a while).

I am looking for the Property MyObject.IsEnabled and would like to reference that in the Path-Property noted with *???* in the code below. Any suggestions?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyObject}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Path="???" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High,Converter={StaticResource debugger}}"  Value="False">
                    <!-- some setters -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

**EDIT:**

Since i want to apply this style to all Cells of my DataGrid later on it is essential to find the object which is bound to the cell via `RelativeSource` instead of adding a hardcoded binding to `MyObject`.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the input of antiocol i was able to find a solution for my case which possibly can be adapted to similar problems.

Since the problem is that we don't have access to the values of the Cell or a `CellModel` from within the `CellStyle`, we use an attached Property on the `DataGridCell` to store the whole `CellModel` in there. From there we can bind any accessible Property of the `DataGridCell` to any Property of our `CellModel`.

**code for attached property:**

```
public static class DataGridUtils
{
public static CellModel GetCellModel(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (CellModel)obj.GetValue(CellModelProperty);
}
public static void SetCellModel(DependencyObject obj, CellModel value)
{
    obj.SetValue(CellModelProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty CellModelProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CellModel", typeof(CellModel), typeof(DataGridUtils), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

We need to set this property on every cell in our DataGrid. I didn't find a good solution to do this in XAML, so for now I set it in the converter before I retrieve the information. (suggestions for improvement appreciated)

**Converter:**

```
public class CellToEnabledConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var cell = values[0] as DataGridCell;
        DataGridTextColumn column = cell.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        //you should probably check if column is null after casting.
        Binding b = column.Binding as Binding;

        //Any suggestions on how to create a Binding to the parent object properly? 
        //I needed this workaround since I bind `MyObject.Value` to the `DataGridTextColumn`, 
        //but need a reference to `MyObject` here.
        Binding b1 = new Binding(b.Path.Path.Split('.')[0]){ Source = cell.DataContext };

        cell.SetBinding(DataGridUtils.CellModelProperty, b1);
        CellModel c = DataGridUtils.GetCellModel(cell);

        return c.IsEnabled;
    }
```

Now we can define a global `Style` in XAML and apply it to the whole `DataGrid` instead of a single column.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:CellToEnabledConverter x:Key="CellToEnabledConverter" />

    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <!--This Converter works only on DataGridTextColumns with this minimal example!-->
                    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource CellToEnabledConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                    </Binding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <!--Setters-->
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyObject.Value}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

Since i found several comments on the net stating that "styling a cell depending on its value just is not possible with the current `DataGrid`", i hope this workaround helps someone out.

Comment: What is `ItemsSource` for `DataGrid`?

Comment: An observable collection of RowModels. You can find my initial question with some details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887303/bind-customobject-to-datagrid . As far as i can tell, the context should not be relevant for this question though.

Comment: `DataContext` of the cell is entire `RowModel`. I'm afraid, you can't get `CellModel` in the style.

Comment: It seems like you are right. However i am really confused why this is not possible. After all i did bind the whole object to my GridCell using `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyObject}">`. Where is this object actually bound to? I went through most of the visual tree (including DataGrid, DataGridView, DataGridCellsPresenter, DataGridCell) and could not find a Property to which `MyObject` is bound. The GUI still shows the proper `ToString()` value of my object, so the reference has to be SOMEwhere?!

Comment: This is how DG built. You've just described binding expression, smth like: "When rendering content of this column, take this property of data context". It's not a "binding of object". So, data context is a `RowModel`. When DG have to render the row, it looks into binding expression for particular column, and resolves its value to render in cell. Resolving doesn't change data context of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying another solution for your problem.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Converter={StaticResource DataGridCellToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyObject1" Binding="{Binding MyObject1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyObject2" Binding="{Binding MyObject2}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the other hand, I assume the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` is a collection of `Element` objects (or something similar, of course)

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyObject MyObject1 { get; set; }
    public MyObject MyObject2 { get; set; }
}
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Finally, the converter:

```
public class DataGridCellToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string propertyToAppend = parameter as string;
        var cell = value as DataGridCell;
        var column = cell.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        Binding b = column.Binding as Binding;
        Binding b1 = new Binding(string.Join(".", b.Path.Path, propertyToAppend)) { Source = cell.DataContext };
        CheckBox dummy = new CheckBox();
        dummy.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, b1);
        return dummy.IsChecked;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The tricky part is using the `ConverterParameter` in order to pass the name of the property you want to bind in the `DataTrigger`.

P.S. You can use reflection instead of the hacky `CheckBox dummy` element, but this works for me.

Hope this helps

Comment: This works and is a way better solution than the `DataGridTemplateColumn` which generates some other issues which i wasn't able to resolve yet. I will probably try to use an attached Property on my DataGridCells and bind the CellModel to that with the code you provided here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal example of my "final" solution. I got two issues left that don't look like *clean* code (setting properties in the converter and manipulating the BindingPath manually to find the correct reference) , but at least it works for now. If you have any suggestions regarding these issues, i would appreciate the input :)

Comment: First, is not necessary to use a MultiValueConverter because you are not passing more than one value to covert. Second, why don't you create an attached property to apply it to `DataGridTextColumn` or even better `DataGridColumn` and hold there the parent property of each set of cells? Later, within the converter, you can read this attached property from `cell.Column` and build the `Binding` in a proper way. What do you think?

Comment: the multiValueConverter was just left over since i passed several parameters for debugging before. I am not quite sure if i understand your second suggestion correctly since binding to the properties of columns is already possible. My issue that i can't specify individual values for cell-properties wouldn't be solved, would it?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is switching each `DataGridTextColumn` to a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and inside each `CellTemplate` add some ContentControl whose DataContext is bound to the property that goes in that column.

That way you can create a reusable Style for that ContentControl, since the `DataGridCell` hasn't been of any help for you :P

```
<Style x:Key="MyObjectStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- your TextBlock and stuff -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, Converter={StaticResource debugger}}"  Value="False">
                <!-- some setters -->
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyObject}"
                            Style="{StaticResource MyObjectStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: The `Triggers` can be inside the `DataTemplate`, too, by the way, if you wanna have easy references to the Controls you place in it.

Comment: ok, so i would need to rebuild a `DataGridTextColumn` if i want to have the exact same functionality, but include databinding to my Cell-ViewModel. I don't like it, but at least it's a solution that should work out. Right now i am trying to use `SortMemberPath` of the `DataGridCell.Column` which contains the reference to `MyObject` (as a string...). If i can get a grip on `MyObject` this way, i could just use a MultiConverter instead of rebuilding the Template.

Comment: Using `SortMemberPath` is too hacky as well, so i am out of other ideas as well.

Comment: I hadn't thought of `SortMemberPath`... It is hacky, but could work with a MultiValueConverter using Reflection, indeed.

Answer (score -1):

You have to fix the sintax of your DataTrigger first, something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyObject}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyObject.IsEnabled, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, Converter={StaticResource debugger}}"  Value="False">
                    <!-- some setters -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Pay attention to the Binding property of the DataTrigger. Is in that property where you have to write your `Path`, in your case `IsEnabled` due to the fact that the `DataContext` in each `DataGridCell` will be an instance of `MyObject` object. You don't need to use the `RelativeSource` because your `Binding` is pointing to `MyObject`, as said before.

If you want to create this style as a resource you can do this:

```
<Style x:Key="cellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyObject.IsEnabled, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, Converter={StaticResource debugger}}"  Value="False">
            <!-- some setters -->
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sadly the DataContext of the DataGridCell points to the DataGridRow as stated by Dennis in the comments. I hoped to find my CellModel there as well, but it seems like this just isn't the way it works.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I've just edited my answer to fix the Path part in the Bindings. As Dennis stated, the DataContext points to the DataGridRow DataContext, so the trick is to indicate the direct parent of IsEnabled property, in this case, MyObject.

Comment: Your code is basically what i am using right now by hardcoding a reference to MyObject into the style for every single column. The Problem with this is that MyObject is a different one for every column, which is why i added the EDIT in my initial post to indicate that i actually need a relative reference to `MyObject` from `DataGridCell` (or any equivalent workaround to find MyObject from within the style). Is that possible?

Comment: The Content of my DataGridCell is a simple TextBlock, so it doesn't contain the required properties either =/

Comment: Do you need to reference a IsEnabled property contained into multiple different objects?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand the question. `MyObject` contains a property `IsEnabled`. Each Cell should contain exactly one instance of `MyObject`, but obviously this instance is different for different cells. However I can not actually find a reference to `MyObject`

Comment: I guess they're different properties of the same type, hence a different Path for Binding...