# Refresh datagrid in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I learning about c# and wpf and i dont know how to deal with something like this:

I have 2 windows (one with usercontrol) and 1 class.

Window1

```
    List<Reservation> reservationList = new List<Reservation>();
    private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (ToggleButton)sender;
            var item = button.DataContext as Hall;
            Reservation nres = new Reservation();
            nres.movieName = item.moviename;
            nres.seat = item.number;
            nres.rowID = item.row;
            reservationList.Add(nres);
        }

        private void Add_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Class contains

```
 class Reservation
{
    public string movieName { get; set; }
    public int seat { get; set; }
    public string rowID { get; set; }
}
```

Window2 have UserControl with datagrid.

Could you give me some advices how to bind window2 usercontrol datagrid to list made in window1, and when i hit ADD button in window1 it refresh that usercontrol and display actual positions in window1 list.

I hope for your understanding and thank you in advance!

Comment: You could for example pass the list to Window2 when you create it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - please verify: Window1 has a radio button (ToggleButton), a push button (Add?), and a list? Window 2 has just a datagrid? The datagrid is what you're calling the "usercontrol"?

Comment: Window2 has usercontrol which contains datagrid and i want to access data to it from window1 list by pushing button in window1

Comment: To store infomation about reservation and i want to show it in user control others window

Comment: @danki: ok, You mean you want to add data to the `DataGridView` on `Window2` when you push the `button` on Window1? If so, where does the data come from (what is the source of the data)? And, what is the ToggleButton for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need two windows, so I'm going to assume you can get by with one window. You don't say so, but I'm assuming that a user will input the movie name, seat number, and row Id into text boxes on the window.

To answer your first question, all you have to do to bind a list to a `DataGrid` is assign the list to the `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` property. For example (See the `MainWindow` method below):

`dataGridReservations.ItemsSource = reservations.List;`

I'm new to WPF, but is seems that the default behavior for a `DataGrid` is to create column names from the names of the variables in the list.

You want to implement your list of reservations as an `ObservableCollection` because an `ObservableCollection` automatically propagates changes to the datagrid when an item is added, deleted, or modified in the bound list. See [How do I bind a List to a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983951/how-do-i-bind-a-listcustomobject-to-a-wpf-datagrid)

For your second question: Use the `Add` button click event to add movie name, seat number, and row Id from the text boxes to a new item in the list. Again, when the list is updated, the `DataGrid` is updated due to the action of the `ObservableCollection`

Here is the code that allows a user to input a movie name, seat number, and row id, and then click the Add button to add it to the `DataGrid`. More code is needed to allow the user to edit or delete an item in the grid.

XAML follows the code

See screen shot at the bottom for a demo

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Reservations reservations;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        reservations = new Reservations();

        dataGridReservations.ItemsSource = reservations.List;
    }

    public class Reservations
    {
        public class Reservation
        {
            private string _movieName;
            private string _seat;
            private string _rowID;

            public Reservation(string movieName, string seat, string rowID)
            {
                MovieName = movieName;
                Seat = seat;
                RowID = rowID;
            }

            public string MovieName { get => _movieName; set => _movieName = value; }
            public string Seat { get => _seat; set => _seat = value; }
            public string RowID { get => _rowID; set => _rowID = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Reservation> _list;

        public ObservableCollection<Reservation> List { get => _list; set => _list = value; }

        public Reservations()
        {
            List = new ObservableCollection<Reservation>();
        }

        public void AddReservationToList(string MovieName, string SeatNumber, string RowId)
        {
            Reservation reservation = new Reservation(MovieName, SeatNumber, RowId);
            List.Add(reservation);
        }

    }

    private void ButtonAddReservationToList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        reservations.AddReservationToList(textBoxMovieName.Text, textBoxSeatNumber.Text, textBoxRowId.Text);
        textBoxMovieName.Text = "";
        textBoxSeatNumber.Text = "";
        textBoxRowId.Text = "";
    }
}
```

**MainWindow XAML**

```html
    <Window x:Class="SO_Refresh_datagrid.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_Refresh_datagrid"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="83,169,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Click="ButtonAddReservationToList"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxMovieName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="140,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxSeatNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="140,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxRowId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="140,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103"/>
            <Label Content="Movie Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="36,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71"/>
            <Label Content="Seat Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="36,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"/>
            <Label Content="Row Id" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="36,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridReservations" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="284" Margin="277,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209"/>
    
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: I was at work yesterday and i hadn't time to answer you. I am very grateful for your answer, it will really help me to understand few things.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reflect changes in a collection your collection should be an Observable collection. See this article how to use an observable collection: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/.

This question is a good example you can use to see the datagrid binding: [MVVM datagrid binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296399/mvvm-datagrid-binding?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) 
When you will add a new reservation to your reservationList (which you make Observable) the change will be reflected in the UI. I hope this will help.

You should follow MVVM pattern when you work with WPF because it will make your life easier. See some tutorial links here : [MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I hope this will help.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, but doesn't answer the "how to bind" question

Comment: Thank you for your answer and few links!