# How to transfer data from Excel to a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, datagridview

I've tried numerous methods I've seen online to copy a Excel file to a DataGridView, but none worked. My main problem is that with those methods there's a problem about fully understanding how they work without a proper explanation or they just give me strange errors, like one that told me that the Excel sheet I wanted to copy was a null instance of an object.
I want to specify that I can easily work on the Excel file with other functions and I get no errors at all, I also don't need any kind of manipulation on the Excel file for this, just a plain way to copy it.
Btw I started using C# just 2 days ago for a stage-thing for school, that's why I don't know much.

Comment: _”I've tried numerous methods I've seen online to copy a Excel file to a DataGridView, but none worked.”_ … ? … Please show what “didn’t” work. It will be difficult to help if we do not know what doesn’t work. What Excel Library are you using… if any?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your Excel-File to a C#-Object, like a List, DataTable, or something else that you can bind to a DataGridView.

Check out [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file), this might get you started.

Then, simply bind to your Object to your DataGridView, e. g. how it was shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983951/how-do-i-bind-a-listcustomobject-to-a-wpf-datagrid).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on your project's name or References and select **Manage NuGet Packages**.
   [image]
2. Under the **Browse** tab, search for **free spire.xls** and install it.
   [image]
3. Use the code below to transfer data from Excel to DataGridView.

   ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Data.xlsx");
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        //Export data in the worksheet to a DataTable 
        DataTable dt = worksheet.ExportDataTable();

        //This overload enables you to specify the range to be exported along with whether to export column names and the actual values of formulas
        //DataTable dt = worksheet.ExportDataTable(worksheet.Range["A1:C10"], true, true);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
   ```